# How to Pass an Object into a Second New Delphi Form

Tags: delphi

I have an object that is created on Form1 and I would like to be able to access one of its fields on Form2.  I have tried to google it and nobody can give an answer that I can understand. Please excuse me but I am a novice.

**Form1**

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
  Ttest=class
    public
    sName:string;
  end;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation

uses Unit2;
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myObj:Ttest;
begin
  myObj.Create;
  myObj.sName := 'Name';
  Form2.Show;
end;

end.
```

**Form2**

```
unit Unit2;
  interface
    uses
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
       Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
   TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
end;

var
 Form2: TForm2;
implementation
uses Unit1;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(myObj.sName);//This is not working
end;

end.
```

Comment: First you need to learn about constructing object instances, you are not creating an instance of Ttest. You are not even creating a Form2, I believe you've pasted some fake code. Second, myObj is not a field of Form1, it is a local variable in some method. You can only access it in the same method that the variable is declared.

Comment: Ok I edited the code to take out the create. It does compile and run if I do not try and ShowMessage myObj. Instead show some other 'string'...... So I can only access myObj in Form1?

Comment: Only in Button1Click, unless you declare myObj in 'interface' or make it a field of TForm1. You create a Ttest like myObj := Ttest.Create;

Comment: Would be kind enough to type that up for me?

Comment: Instead of declaring `myObj` in the local procedure, you need to declare it on a level which is accessible by the other form. This means either in the interface section, or inside of your `TForm1`, as Sertac says. I suggest you study up on declaring variables in Delphi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two forms that both use an object. You should define the object in a separate unit and list it in the Uses clause in the Interface section of both forms. Try using something already defined in a main library, like TStringlist, so you don't get confused with this part.

From what you're showing here, you're attempting to create an instance of that object in one form and do something with it in another form. That's a common thing to do: you may have one unit that asks for a filename and loads a file into a TStringList, then hands that over to another form or unit to deal with.

The way you're doing it, however, can be improved to reduce coupling between the two forms.

What you want to do is define a property like this in TForm2:

```
TForm2 = class( TForm )
. . .
private
  Ftestobj : TTest; // or TStringlist

public
  property testobj : TTest read Ftestobj write Ftestobj;
```

Then in TForm1.OnButtonClick do something like this:

```
form2.testobj := myobj;
form2.Show;
```

And then this becomes:

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(Ftestobj.sName);
end;
```

I did a whole session in CodeRage 9 on this topic recently, in fact. It's entitled, "Have you embraced your inner plumber yet?" and it's all about moving data in and out of forms like this. (I call it plumbing code.)

Search for "coderage 9" and watch the video. At the end is a link where you can download my example code. That should keep you busy for a while. :)